# Is it bad to use a lot of polymorphism?

Tags: oop, polymorphism

I've heard that using a lot of polymorphism is bad and that it's better code design to avoid polymorphism where ever possible. Is this true?

Comment: Polymorphism, like reflection, requires you to run your code to be sure what it does. You can't just read a piece of code and be sure which path it's going to take (because it depends on the program's input). Unless you're under bureaucracy from your management (or a low-functioning technical interviewer), I would advise you to keep your code as simple and stupid as possible - a bit like C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, quite a few design patterns are implemented primarily using polymorphism. The factory pattern is one of the more common patterns that use it.

It is a fundamental part of object oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to be sure.

Comment: There is a body of evidence that design patterns, and OOP itself are bad. So saying polymorphism is good because design patterns use it, and that it's fundamental to OOP is a premise a lot of programmers don't even realize.

Answer (score 1):

you probably heard that about Inheritance. The design principle being favor object composition  over class inheritance.